# What do I do to make my normal map look right? All of the shading is different according to the uv unwrapped mesh

Tags: modeling, shaders, sculpting, uv-image-editor, normal-map

Im trying to bake a normal map onto my retopo. And although it looks like the map got all of the detail from the sculpt in. it seems that it has shaded all of the islands of the uv map differently. I don't know how to fix this. Is it a lighting issue or something simple that i'm missing[image]

Comment: Hello what does it give if you switch the Image Texture from sRGB to Non-Color?

Comment: Lol. I new it was something tiny. Thanks. Non color works.

Comment: Could you formulate your comment in an answer and mark it as complete, so the solution is clear to everyone and easier to find, thanks.